# How can I retrieve the profile2 fields selected in a custom module?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I am totally new to entities in Drupal.  I have used the Profile2 module to add a few profile types.  This is displayed in the add/user screen as Customer.

After adding the profile type I manage the fields and add a new entry called `cust` with a `field_id` of `field_cid`.  This is setup as a list(text) and checkbox widget.

When I edit a user I have a checkbox list for Customer that can be selected by each user.  I have a custom module that I am trying to read the selected value by `$user->uid` from the profile2 field.

The idea is to retrieve the selected item in my module and format the return values to the user from a custom DB table.  Here is what I have tried and got results but cannot get all the values.

In my module using:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid);$list = field_view_field('profile2', $profile['customer'], 'field_cid');print_r($list)
```

I get this result:

```
Array ( [#theme] => field [#weight] => 0 [#title] => cust [#access] => 1 [#label_display] => above [#view_mode] => _custom_display [#language] => und [#field_name] => field_cid [#field_type] => list_text [#field_translatable] => 0 [#entity_type] => profile2 [#bundle] => customer [#object] => Profile Object ( [pid] => 9 [type] => customer [label] => Customer [uid] => 1 [created] => 1409542969 [changed] => 1409545821 [entityType:protected] => profile2 [entityInfo:protected] => Array ( [label] => Profile [plural label] => Profiles [description] => Profile2 user profiles. [entity class] => Profile [controller class] => EntityAPIController [base table] => profile [fieldable] => 1 [view modes] => Array ( [account] => Array ( [label] => User account [custom settings] => ) ) [entity keys] => Array ( [id] => pid [bundle] => type [label] => label [revision] => ) [bundles] => Array ( [customer] => Array ( [label] => Customer [admin] => Array ( [path] => admin/structure/profiles/manage/%profile2_type [real path] => admin/structure/profiles/manage/customer [bundle argument] => 4 [access arguments] => Array ( [0] => administer profiles ) ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) ) ) [bundle keys] => Array ( [bundle] => type ) [label callback] => entity_class_label [uri callback] => entity_class_uri [access callback] => profile2_access [module] => profile2 [metadata controller class] => Profile2MetadataController [static cache] => 1 [field cache] => 1 [load hook] => profile2_load [translation] => Array ( ) [schema_fields_sql] => Array ( [base table] => Array ( [0] => pid [1] => type [2] => uid [3] => label [4] => created [5] => changed ) ) [configuration] => ) [idKey:protected] => pid [nameKey:protected] => pid [statusKey:protected] => status [defaultLabel:protected] => [field_cid] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => 2 ) ) ) [field_test] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 3 ) ) ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) ) [#items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => 2 ) ) [#formatter] => list_default [0] => Array ( [#markup] => Disney ) [1] => Array ( [#markup] => Burger King ) )
```

I want the name in the last line `[#markup]` only returned to my function.  In the above output the returned values should be *Disney* and *Burger King*.

How can I retrieve these values only?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is giving me the results I am after:

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid);
$customer = field_get_items('profile2', $profile['customer'], 'field_cid');
$key = array();
foreach($customer as $item=>$value){
  $output = field_view_value('profile2', $profile['customer'], 'field_cid', $customer[$item]);
  $key[] = strip_tags(render($output));
}
foreach($key as $word) {
  echo $word . "</br>";
}
```